# Converting a 2D array (adjacency list) into a dictionary python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, 2d, adjacency-list

My adjacency list is:

```
Graph = [[3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2]]
```

I would like to get this output:

```
adjacency_dict = {0: [3, 4], 
                  1: [3], 
                  2: [3, 4], 
                  3: [0, 1, 2], 
                  4: [0, 2]}
```

All of the previous solutions I've tried have gotten me "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'", which I understand conceptually why I get but I can't convert that understanding into actually writing a solution. I am relatively new to Python so any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: `adjacency_dict  = {i: l for (i,l) in enumerate(Graph)}` although I don't see the point of doing this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
adjacency_dict = {i: j for i,j in enumerate(Graph)}
```

or

```
adjacency_dict = {i:Graph[i] for i in range(len(Graph))}
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically the outcome you are trying to achieve with the dictionary will be same with the list.

For example try this

```
>>>Graph[0][1]
//will print 4
>>>Graph[1][0]
//will print 3
```

But if you really want to convert the list to a dictionary with key you described can be done in following code:

```
adjacency_dict = {}
for idx, val in enumerate(Graph):
  adjacency_dict[idx] = val
```

Answer (score 1):

Though a dict comprehension yields the same result, I find this more concise:

```
adjacency_dict = dict(enumerate(Graph))
```